# Invalid character found in base64 while deploying model on TF Serving locally, is it safe to remove the '='?

Tags: python, base64, padding, tensorflow-serving

I have a TF model (TF version 2.0) that is deployed on my own premises. My model expects a string as input and the first layer decodes this base64 encoded string. It works well when I submit a request to server like the following one:

```
header = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
url = 'http://.../v1/models/mymodel:predict'
raw_data = '{"signature_name": "serving_default", "instances": [{"b64_image": "_9j_4AA...Qs__2Q"}]}'
response = requests.post(url=url,data=raw_data,headers=header)
```

But if I add a `=` at the end of the image string, I get an error `Invalid character found in base64`. The `=` character comes from a third party application that applies padding when encoding (like base64.urlsafe_b64encode from Python). Is it safe to remove all `=` characters at the end before requesting TF Serving?

Comment: ``=``-padding is part of base64. Either your base64 consuming or producing function is broken – either the consumer should process it with the correct padding, or the producer should not have created the incorrect padding.

Comment: you're right, thanks!